# Is there a Unix system call to truncate a file at current offset

Tags: linux, file, unix

Is there a Linux api to truncate an open file at the current offset?
I can do lseek() followed by ftruncate(), but was trying to save a system call.

Answer (score -1):

ftell() is your friend here:

```
/* do operations on file, such as fread() or fwrite() */
curpos = ftell(filehandle);
if (result = ftruncate(filehandle, curpos)) {
    /* handle the error condition, examine errno etc */
    exit(errno);
}
```

Comment: ftruncate takes an `off_t` in bytes, but `ftell` does not necessarily return an offset in bytes.

Comment: You are correct, I should have specified the use of ftello() instead.